# Store View Pricing with currency convert support

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5p1

On our website we have multiple store views like- uk, eu, and com
Currencies for these store view:-
uk => British Pound,
eu => Euro,
com => USD

We are using a Bss Commerce extension for store view pricing but we have a problem when we enable this extension the currency converter(British Pound to USD) stops working (maybe after changing the base currency for store view).

We want currency converter because we have many other products for which we do not want to add their store view pricing directly.

Is there any solution to it?

Magento 2.4.5-p1 version.

Comment: Can we skip the currency converter for some specific products?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. is anyone in the community provide any solution for this issue?